# Utility methods in ASM bytecode library for opcode nature determination?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

Are there any utils classes in ASM that allows me to infer from the opcode whether the instruction is some kind of store, load, or whatever?

For instance, and considering the following code (from ASM)

```
/**
 * Visits a zero operand instruction.
 *
 * @param opcode the opcode of the instruction to be visited. This opcode is
 *        either NOP, ACONST_NULL, ICONST_M1, ICONST_0, ICONST_1, ICONST_2,
 *        ICONST_3, ICONST_4, ICONST_5, LCONST_0, LCONST_1, FCONST_0,
 *        FCONST_1, FCONST_2, DCONST_0, DCONST_1, IALOAD, LALOAD, FALOAD,
 *        DALOAD, AALOAD, BALOAD, CALOAD, SALOAD, IASTORE, LASTORE, FASTORE,
 *        DASTORE, AASTORE, BASTORE, CASTORE, SASTORE, POP, POP2, DUP,
 *        DUP_X1, DUP_X2, DUP2, DUP2_X1, DUP2_X2, SWAP, IADD, LADD, FADD,
 *        DADD, ISUB, LSUB, FSUB, DSUB, IMUL, LMUL, FMUL, DMUL, IDIV, LDIV,
 *        FDIV, DDIV, IREM, LREM, FREM, DREM, INEG, LNEG, FNEG, DNEG, ISHL,
 *        LSHL, ISHR, LSHR, IUSHR, LUSHR, IAND, LAND, IOR, LOR, IXOR, LXOR,
 *        I2L, I2F, I2D, L2I, L2F, L2D, F2I, F2L, F2D, D2I, D2L, D2F, I2B,
 *        I2C, I2S, LCMP, FCMPL, FCMPG, DCMPL, DCMPG, IRETURN, LRETURN,
 *        FRETURN, DRETURN, ARETURN, RETURN, ARRAYLENGTH, ATHROW,
 *        MONITORENTER, or MONITOREXIT.
 */
public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
    if (mv != null) {
        mv.visitInsn(opcode);
    }
}
```

it would be handy to have methods such as Utils.isConst(opcode) or Utils.isLoad(opcode) or Utils.isStore(opcode).

Is there anything like it in ASM?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`InstructionAdapter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/InstructionAdapter.html). It translates opcodes into more coarse-grained method calls.

Comment: Hmm. it seems tailored to generate code. I actually needed it to do some sort of analysis (when given opcode X, know if it's a store or a load, for instance).